# SSL with SocketIO

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ssl, socket.io

I am working on a project which is using nodeJs/socket.io. Web page is secured with ssl, but socket.io connection has no ssl.

I am getting this error:

```
The page at 'https://www.mydomain.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed
insecure content from 'http://socket.io.connection:1234/socket.io/1/?t=1390397': 
this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

I know,  I need to use SSL for socket.io too, but I really dont know how it works.

- Do I need only one certificate for web and socket.io?
- Can I use 2 different certificate and bind them somehow together?
- How can I use only one SSL certificate for 2 different servers?

Comment: Are they different domains?

Comment: yes, they are different

Comment: Web and socket.io can share a cert, but I don't know if multiple domains can.